# Android Junit4 test skipped by AndroidJUnitRunner and ProviderTestCase2 generates NullPointerException within tearDown()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, junit4

I'd like to get some help determining how my `@Test` is getting skipped.  I'll explain what I've been through in working through the issue. Using the test, included below, the test runner hits `setUp()` and `tearDown()` but not the test annotated as `@Test` and shown below as `testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly`

The test's "Run/Debug Configuration" "Specific instrumentation runner" setting is set to `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

I've built the following test to be run against the StorageProvider sample application provided through `File -> New -> Import Sample` from Android Studio 1.5.1, with the gradle plugin version 1.5.0.  I believe that I have followed the instructions found within [ContentProviderTesting](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/integration-testing/content-provider-testing.html) to build the test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyCloudProviderTest extends ProviderTestCase2 {
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.storageprovider.documents";
    private static final String FILENAME = "foo";
    private static final String LOGTAG = "MCPT";
    private File mFile;

    public MyCloudProviderTest() {
        super(MyCloudProvider.class, AUTHORITY);
    }

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Setting Up MyCloudProviderTest");
        setContext(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        super.setUp();
        super.testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly();
        mFile = new File(getMockContext().getFilesDir().getPath(), FILENAME);
        if (!mFile.exists()) {
            mFile.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Test
    public void testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly() {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "testing AndroidTestCaseSetupProperly");
        super.testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly();
        assertTrue(mFile.exists());
        assertNotNull(getProvider());
    }

    @Override
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Tearing Down MyCloudProviderTest");
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Within my module's build.gradle, I've included the dependencies shown below, as well as the configuration under `android -> defaultConfig -> testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` as instructed in the [Testing Support Library Setup Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#setup)
The module's build.gradle is included here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The projections build.gradle includes

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

When running these tests, I can confirm that the `@Test` annotation is skipped by placing a breakpoint within it, or reading logcat, which reads as follows (note the lack of "testing AndroidTestCaseSetupProperly"):

```
02-09 12:46:05.717 26129-26157/com.example.android.storageprovider V/MCPT: Setting Up MyCloudProviderTest
02-09 12:46:05.724 26129-26157/com.example.android.storageprovider V/MCPT: Tearing Down MyCloudProviderTest
```

I have searched pretty widely, looking for something to clarify why the @Test annotated method has been skipped, but what cases I have seen do not appear to be applicable for `JUnit4` testing a subclass of `ProviderTestCase2`

Beyond, skipping the `@Test` method, the code also throws the following stack trace.  I have combined these issues, as they are almost certainly related, and may in fact shed light on one another:

```
Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.ContentProvider.shutdown()' on a null object reference
at android.test.ProviderTestCase2.tearDown(ProviderTestCase2.java:167)
at com.example.android.storageprovider.MyCloudProviderTest.tearDown(MyCloudProviderTest.java:47)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

Comment: did you every find the answer to this?